# Adding a list of years inside a jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm a begginer programmer and my problem is I have no idea on how to put a list of years in a JComboBox from the current date to 80 years in the past. I could do a string like this,

```
String Y_tmp[]={"1934","1935","1936","1937"}; //-all the way to current year
JComboBox Y = new JComboBox(Y_tmp);
```

However that looks very messy and does not automatically change to the next year upon the new year.
It also does not remove the last year from the beggining of the list. Does anyone know how to do what I am wanting to do?

Comment: `However that looks very messy and does not automatically change to the next year upon the new year.`  == yes exactly, 2. `Does anyone know how to do what I am wanting to do?` == for better help sooner post an `SSCCE`/`MCVE`, short, runnable, compilable, 3. before anything here to read Oracle tutorials `a)` how to use Spinners, `b)` lists and `c)` last one could be about Combobox

Comment: So your problem as I understand is to render a dynamically changing drop box that maintains a list of 80 years dynamically, is that correct?

Comment: @mKorbel, what is SSCCE/MCVE?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @Sid 1. [SSCCE](https://www.google.sk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1GTPM_enSK584SK584&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ie=UTF-8&q=sscce&safe=active) and [MCVE](https://www.google.sk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1GTPM_enSK584SK584&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=mcve), 2. hope that help you (true is, all are made by google), 3. really the time to read FAQ here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this, in the prop of combobox:

```
ArrayList<String> years_tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int years = 1980; years<=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR); years++) {
    years_tmp.add(years+"");
}
jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(years_tmp.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is..

```
for(int i=1950;i<=2019;i++){
        jComboBox3.addItem(i);
}
```

You are all done